# Xml tags all on a single row

Tags: asp.net

im creating a sitemap.xml in asp and i would like to have as output xml this (example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>11111</loc>
<lastmod>2012-05-03T23:00:00Z</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

unfortunately if i display my xml with notepad have all in a single row as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>11111</loc><lastmod>2012-05-03T23:00:00Z</lastmod><changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>1.0</priority></url>
</urlset>
```

to generate xml node im using createnode xmldom method! where is my fault????

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT to generate your XML, you should be able to specify then **indent** attribute on the **xsl:output** element at the top of your stylesheet.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
```

If the only reason you wish to indent the document is to make it easier for you to read and edit manually, it might be worth using a different editor to look at the files than Notepad. (I use Notepad++, for example, and that can indent XML).

Comment: Im generating my xml from asp script, xml generated looks fine on ie browser with right indentation, problem is on editor as notepad or Dreamweaver 8, here i see all on a row.

Comment: @Massimo: In case you don't want an XSLT solution, please, retag and remove the "xslt" tag.

Comment: i got solution [link](http://hsteinhilber.blogspot.it/2010/09/wshbuild-progress-sort-of.html)

Comment: @Massimo: You can update your question to make it clear this is an ASP.Net issue, not an XSLT. You can also answer your own question with the solution, as that will help others who may come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `createwhitespace`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createwhitespace.aspx

Comment: is a xmldom method or property?

Comment: i found preserveWhiteSpace but nothing happens